# .trigger() jquery not working in mobiles

Tags: jquery

My trigger works in desktop but does not work in mobiles:
The code is"

```
$( "#foo" ).click(function() {
$( "#bar").trigger( "click" );
});
```

How Do i get it to work in mobiles too?

Comment: It will trigger the click event. Maybe there is no click event bound on mobile, who knows? How do you debug it? Is at least the `#foo` click event fired? You have too provide minimalistic sample to replicate issue. Here your code is ***too*** minimalistic to make your question clear enough

Comment: Yes the #foo event is fired; I have tested that.